# Geofenceの結果を受け取る方法について教えてください。

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-service

お世話になっております。
　
質問：Geofenceの結果を受け取る方法について教えてください。

前回、Geofenceについて教えていただき、下記のサンプルの改良品を動作できておりました。
参考サイト
http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/android/android-google-play-services-location-api-geofencing/

最近、次の改良に移ろうと動作確認を行ったところ、携帯の「ホームボタン」を押した際に誤動作を行うことがわかりました。
　「リターンキー」ではアプリは正常に動作しましたが、「ホームボタン」で画面を移動し再度アプリに戻った際、「onNewIntent」が動作し、「Geofence範囲外」でも処理してしまいます。
　原因は、製作時でも気になっていた「Geofence」以外の「Intent」を拾ったものと思っています。
　回避方法として、「onNewIntent」の勉強と「IntentService」の実装を試みています。
　
　現状説明
　「onNewIntent」：
　「GeofenceでのIntent」判定で最適な方法にたどりついておりません。
　　最悪「if」で判定できないか？とも考えております。

「IntentService」：
　　ReceiveTransitionsIntentService.javaを自動で制作。
　　MainActivity.javaのpendingIntentを
　　Intent intent = new Intent(self, MainActivity.class);
　　から
　　Intent intent = new Intent(self, ReceiveTransitionsIntentService.class);
　　に変更。
　　ReceiveTransitionsIntentService.javaのonHandleIntentで結果を受けようとしま　したが動作できておりません。
　AndroidManifest.xmlには、
　android:name=".ReceiveTransitionsIntentService"
  android:exported="false" >
が自動的に記載されております。

各項目でのアドバイス、または、Geofenceの結果を受け取り、処理するのに適した他の方法がありましたら、ご指摘いただけたら幸いです。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Intent`の`Action`を指定して、それで判断すればいいと思います。

適当な`Action`を作成

```
private static final String ACTION_GEOFENCE_UPDATE = "intent.action.GEOFENCE_UPDATE";
```

`Intent`が飛んできたところ

```
if (ACTION_GEOFENCE_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    // Geofenceの処理
}
```

`Intent`を作るところ

```
Intent intent = new Intent(・・・・・・);
intent.setAction(ACTION_GEOFENCE_UPDATE);
```

Comment: お忙しい中、ご回答をいただきありがとうございます。
　早速、試したところ正常動作させることが出来ました。
　問題は解決しましたが、「IntentService」の動作不全と「他の処理方法」について皆様のご意見をお伺いしたため、しばらくこのまま質問を続けたいと思います。
　yuki様、ありがとうございました。